# Is it possible to make a Telerik report based on an existing PDF?

Tags: pdf, telerik, report, converters

I have a lengthy PDF time tracking document that was printed out and used in a paper process to schedule appointments. Now this paper process is being converted to an online application and this application needs to generate reports in the same format as the PDF document (this time programatically inserting values into rows instead of having someone write them on the piece of paper).

My question is this, is possible to somehow import the layout of that PDF document into Telerik reporter's designer? Otherwise, is there some sort of an intermediary tool that I can use to make the layout more exportable?

Just to clarify, I am not trying to save my reports as PDF but trying to use a given PDF's layout to create a similar looking report in Telerik.

Any tips would be very welcome.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous tools for extracting text or images from pdf files, but I am pretty sure nothing exists to extract the layout of a pdf. The pdf format is just text and symbols with coordinates. There is no layout to extract.